# Use Textured Strand Lap Siding or concrete board to attach outside deck trim

Tags: deck, siding, lumber

I want to "cover" the outside of the deck trim because the look of treated wood isn't good. But if I use deck material (composite) to run around, it's going to be expensive. I am planning to just use Textured Strand Lap Siding / Concrete Board because they are cheap and durable. But I have several questions:

1. Can Textured Strand Lap Siding attach to treated lumber using screws without causing problems (like loosen over the year or chemical reaction)?
2. The board is 0.5" thick and I plan to paint similar color (I can match). Is this a good idea in general, especially coming to durability?

The board I like to get is "SmartSide 8 in. x 144 in. Textured Strand Lap Siding" (just FYI) from home improvement store.

Comment: Cement board and composit wood expand ad diferent rates if a good gap is filled with silicone caulk of the right color or painted I have had some good luck mixing materials similar to your question.

Comment: Composite expands and contracts to a greater degree than wood. Here's a video about [a trim product for composite boards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqPQA4yrqZA) (I think it might help to study the design). And here's [a video about the trim product's failure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2YBRr8ivY4)

Comment: I don't plan to have cement board and composite deck "touching" at all. The board will attach to the treated lumber trim joists around the deck and it will be below the decking boards. But would the 0.5" board be OK (without breaking or cracking I guess) to attach to treated lumber?

Comment: If you nail it every foot, it shouldn't move (much). To prevent splitting, drill pilot holes. Use a corner that allows/hides expansion and contraction of the siding. **I think it might help to study the design of the corner shown in the video from my previous comment ([a trim product for composite boards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqPQA4yrqZA)).**